# Can you find the number of different values of an attribute w. jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I have a structure like so:

```
<div class='collection'>
    <div class='item' seq=1>foo</div>
    <div class='item' seq=2>bar</div>
    <div class='item' seq=2>baz</div>
    <div class='item' seq=2>asd</div>
    <div class='item' seq=3>que</div>
    <div class='item' seq=3>bletch</div>
</div>
```

It's easy to get the number of items with seq=1, seq=2, etc.  But how would you find the number of different values of seq, and what those values are?  It's probably safe to assume that the values of `seq` will start at 1 and go up by 1 until there are no more.

Comment: To create valid HTML you should use a `data-*`-attribute like: `data-seq=""`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accumulate the attribute values and their count in an object:

```
var totals = {};
$(".collection > .item").each(function() {
    var seq = $(this).attr("seq");
    var total = totals[seq] || 0;
    totals[seq] = total + 1;
});
```

When the above code has run, you should have an object like:

```
{
    "1": 1,
    "2": 3,
    "3": 2
}
```

Comment: If it's possible the `seq` attribute isn't there, you can filter a little more: `".collection > .item[seq]"`. That way you'd avoid having an `undefined` as one of your keys. Unless you want that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var items = [];
$(".collection > .item").each(function() {
   var sequence = $(this).attr("seq");
    if (jQuery.inArray(sequence, items) == -1) {
         items.push(sequence);
    }
});
```

This would declare an array called items and loop round each div. If the sequence is not in the array it adds the sequence value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(".item")` instead of `$(".collection")`?

Comment: @insertusernamehere - yes good spot.  I have added .collection > .item as it is a descendant of colleciton.